# How to ignore Invoke-Webrequest Errormessage

Tags: powershell

I have a - in my opinion - strange case where PowerShell throws an error, even though I'm trying to ignore it. What's also strange, it's a terminating error, meaning the whole function stops even though it shouldn't

This is my function, which I use to get breached E-Mail Accounts of my company, by using the `haveibeenpwned` API.

```
function Get-Pwned {

    Param(
        [Parameter( Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string[]]$EmailAddress,
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$API = "https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/breachedaccount/"
    )

    Begin { 

        $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

        # Setzen der Anfrage auf TLS 1.2, da TLS 1.0 nicht akzeptiert wird
        [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

        # ResultArray
        $Pwned = @()
    }

    # über Mail Adressen loopen und schauen ob 
    Process {
        foreach ($Email in $EmailAddress)
        {
            $Uri = "{0}{1}" -f $API, $Email
            Write-Host $Uri
            Invoke-WebRequest $Uri -ea Ignore | select -expand Content | ConvertFrom-Json |
                        foreach { 
                            $Pwned += [PSCustomObject]@{ 
                                Email = $Email
                                Name = $_.Name
                                Domain = $_.Domain
                                BreachDate = $_.BreachDate 
                            }
                        }
        }
    }

    End {
        # Return Object
        $Pwned
    }
}
```

the [Documentation](https://haveibeenpwned.com/API/v2) of the API says, that if there's no breach found for an e-mail address, I will get a status code 404 in return.

my Problem is, whenever this happens, i get a completely terminating error. so basically, when an E-Mail Adress isn't pwned (which is  good thing), the execution of the script stops completely (which is not a good thing).

as you can see I'm trying to do `$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"` and `-ea Ignore` but I still get the error message and my script still stops.

I use the function like this:

```
Get-Mailbox foo@bar.com | select -expand EmailAddresses | ? { $_.startswith("smtp:") } | % { $_.split(":")[1] } | Get-Pwned
```

if you want to test it you can simply do it like this:

`"email@server.com", "email2@server.com" | get-pwned`

That's the error I'm getting:

> Invoke-WebRequest : Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben:
>   (404) Nicht gefunden. In
>   \server\Powershell-Scripts\Functions\Get-Pwned.ps1:27
>   Zeichen:13
>   +             Invoke-WebRequest $Uri -ea Ignore | select -expand Conten ...
>   +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest],
>   WebException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

How can I get my script not to stop when there's an error message, and how can I ignore it, so that i don't get n error message?

**Edit:**
I just noticed, it works if I do it like this:

```
$addr = "email@server.com", "email2@server.com"
Get-Pwned $addr
```

Why doesn't it work with Pipeline input?

Comment: It shouldn't be throwing a terminating error especially given the lengths you're going to.  As a last resort, you can wrap the command in a try/catch block.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 yes, `try / catch` works. thanks a lot! I find it still very strange though, since I'm ignoring the error already. If you want you can expand your command to an answer, i'll gladly accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain why you're still getting script-terminating errors when setting `-ErrorAction`, but you can work around this problem by instead wrapping the command in a `try`/`catch` block:

```
try
{
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -ErrorAction Stop |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object { 
            $Pwned += [pscustomobject]@{ 
                Email = $Email
                Name = $_.Name
                Domain = $_.Domain
                BreachDate = $_.BreachDate 
            }
        }
}
catch
{
    Write-Warning -Message "Error returned! $_"
}
```

As a footnote, `-ErrorAction` takes precedence over `$ErrorActionPreference`.